# Is it an AJAX call or an asynchronous JavaScript call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asynchronous, jsonp

I have been working with AJAX, JSON and JSONP for the last few months, and now I am trying to revisit and build my basics. AJAX is Asynchronous JavaScript And XML, assuming that XML is the data format in which the server returns the data. If no data type is specified, it actually comes back as plain text. So if I am ingesting a JSON feed using the XMLHttpRequest object, can I still call it an AJAX call or should I call it an asynchronous JavaScript call??

```
ex: $.getJSON("data.json", function(data){
         console.log(data);
    })
```

Just a random question to make sure that I know what I am talking about, mainly when I talk to developers who are specific about the terms that I use and the context that I use them in.

Comment: AJAX is becoming a general term for asynchronous calls. It's fine to use it even when the returned data is not XML. Besides, Json is often used more than XML.

Comment: At this point in time AJAX has evolved to mean "Asynchronous Javascript And X" where "X" here simply means data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term AJAX has come to represent any networking call made from within a page using javascript (other than a websocket), whether the returned data is XML or not.  In fact, it's now common to get JSON as the returned data type (a format that wasn't even standard back when the term AJAX was coined).

So ... it works perfectly fine to refer to a call as an AJAX call even though the returned data type is something other than XML.